Prove that the sum of all the product of n entries, no two of which are in the same row or column is divisible by $4$.
I found this problem in A path to combinatorics for undergraduates. This is problem 9.58.
Let $n$ be a positive integer with $n\geq 4$. Each entry in an $n\times n$ matrix is either $1$ or $-1$. A base is defined to be the product of $n$ entries, no two of which are in the same row or column. Prove that the sum of all the bases is divisible by $4$.
I've figured that $n\geq 4$ is a necessary condition since for $n=1,2$ or $3$, an $n\times n$ matrix in which every entry is set to $1$ is a counterexample to that claim. I also figured that the sum can be written as $\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i\pi(i)}$. Now I don't know how to proceed. Any hint or solution would be appreciated. Thank you.

Let $X_n$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrix in which each entry is 1 or -1.
It can be proved by induction that $\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{1i} \operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})$, where $A_{1j}$ represents the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ $(i,j)$-minor, for any $A\in X_n$ and any $n\geq 2$.
It is clear that $\operatorname*{per}(A)\in \{0,\pm 2\}$ for any $A\in X_2$.
We now show that $\operatorname*{per}(A)\in \{\pm 2,\pm6\}$ for any $A\in X_3$.
Pick any $A\in X_3$. We have $\operatorname*{per}(A)=\sum_{i = 1}^3 a_{1i} \operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})$, where $A_{1j}$ represents the $2\times 2$ $(i,j)$-minor. Notice that $a_{1i}\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})\in  \{0,\pm 2\}$ for any $i\in \{1,2,3\}$. If $a_{1i}\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})\ne 0$ for any $i\in \{1,2,3\}$, then $\operatorname*{per}(A)\in \{\pm 2,\pm6\}$.
Suppose $a_{1i}\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})=0$ for some $i\in \{1,2,3\}$. W.L.O.G, let $i=1$, then we have $a_{22}a_{33}+a_{23}a_{32}=\operatorname*{per}(A_{11})=0$. So the entries of exactly one of the column differ by a sign. W.G.O.G, set $a_{22}=-1$ and $a_{33}=a_{23}=a_{32}=1$.
We have the following cases
Case 1: Suppose $a_{21}a_{31}=1$. W.L.O.G, set $a_{21}=a_{31}=1$. Then we have $\operatorname*{per}(A_{12})=a_{21}a_{33}+a_{31}a_{23}=1+1=2$ and $\operatorname*{per}(A_{13})=a_{21}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{31}=1-1=0$. So $\operatorname*{per}(A)=\pm 2$.
Case 2: Suppose $a_{21}a_{31}=-1$. W.L.O.G, set $a_{21}=1$ and $a_{31}=-1$. Then we have $\operatorname*{per}(A_{12})=a_{21}a_{33}+a_{31}a_{23}=1-1=0$ and $\operatorname*{per}(A_{13})=a_{21}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{31}=1+1=2$. So $\operatorname*{per}(A)=\pm 2$.
Combining the above results, we have $\operatorname*{per}(A)\in \{\pm 2,\pm6\}$.
Now we prove that $4|\operatorname*{per}(A)$ for any $A\in X_4$.
Pick any $A\in X_4$. We have $\operatorname*{per}(A)=\sum_{i = 1}^4 a_{1i} \operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})$, where $A_{1j}$ represents the $3\times 3$ $(i,j)$-minor. For any $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, as $\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})\in \{\pm 2,\pm6\}$ and $a_{1i}\in \{1,-1\}$, we have $a_{1i}\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})\in \{\pm 2,\pm6\}$. So we have $a_{1i}\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})=2 \pmod 4$.So
$$\operatorname*{per}(A)=\sum_{i = 1}^4 a_{1i} \operatorname*{per}(A_{1i}) \equiv 4(2) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$
It follows that $4|\operatorname*{per}(A)$ for any $A\in X_4$.
We may then proceed by induction and using the formula $\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{1i} \operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})$ to prove that $4|\operatorname*{per}(A)$ for any $A\in X_n$ and any $n\geq 4$.

Note that this 'sum of bases' represents the permanent of the matrix. Let $v_n$ be defined as the largest positive integer such that $2^{v_n}$ divides the permanents of all such matrices. Then we see $v_1 = 0$ and $v_2 = 1$. We will now show $v_m + v_n \leq v_{m+n}$ for all positive integers $m, n$.
There are $(m + n)!$ bases of a matrix of size $m + n$, each of which can be split into groups of size $m! n!$, with the set of first $m$ columns in the base corresponding to the first $m$ rows, and the next $n$ columns in the base corresponding to the bottom $n$ rows. We see the sum of these bases in the two splits multiply to be equal to the product of the permanent of an $m \times m$ matrix and an $n \times n$ matrix.
Hence, $2^{v_m} 2^{v_n} \mid 2^{v-{m + n}}$, and hence we get $v_n \geq \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor$

Could you please explain why is it that when n is even, $2^{v_n + 1}$ divides $\operatorname*{per}(A)$? I mean if we factor $2^{v_n}$ from each permanent of the minors we would get a product of $2^{v_n}$ and a sum of even number of integers, but a sum of even number of integers is not necessarily even.

@19021605 Hmmm I see what you're saying, I'll think about this some more. I'm sure the argument is almost sufficient enough for what you want. I really shouldn't be doing maths in the middle of the night !_!

After some research, I discovered that your result has also been proved by induction in this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760844. However, the details are omitted and I don't know how to fill it in though.

@19021605 I think I have a more complete solution now, hope that helps!

The step "the sum of these bases in the two splits multiply to be equal to the product of the permanent of an $m\times m$ matrix and an $n\times n$ matrix." has the problem that we can't get a base whose entry comes from the top right $m\times n$ submatrix or the lower left $n\times m$ submatrix from expanding the product.
